# HttpRequestMessage.GetClientCertificate() not working with Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I've written the following azure function..(quick and short version of issue)

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;

namespace GranadaCoder.AzurePoc.AzureFunctionsOne
{
    public static class ClientCertificateTest
    {
        [FunctionName("ClientCertificateTestFunctionName")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 cert = req.GetClientCertificate();

                X509Certificate2 headerCert = null;
                System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpRequestHeaders headers = req.Headers;
                if (headers.Any(x => x.Key.Equals("X-ARR-ClientCert", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
                {
                    IEnumerable<string> headerValues = headers.GetValues("X-ARR-ClientCert");
                    if (null != headerValues)
                    {
                        var certHeader = headerValues.FirstOrDefault();
                        byte[] clientCertBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(certHeader);
                        headerCert = new X509Certificate2(clientCertBytes);
                    }
                }

                string msg = (null == cert ? "NO CERT :(" : string.Format("We got a cert! '{0}'", cert.Subject)) + " " + (null == headerCert ? "NO headerCert :(" : string.Format("We got a headerCert! '{0}'", headerCert.Subject));

                HttpContent content = req.Content;
                string contentString = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                msg += String.IsNullOrEmpty(contentString) ? ", no content" : ", " + contentString;

                return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, msg);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = ex.Message; //  ExceptionHelper.GenerateFullFlatMessage(ex);
                log.Error(errorMsg);
                return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, errorMsg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've written the following "Client" code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GranadaCoder.SendWebRequests.ConsoleOne
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("START : {0}", System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);

                X509Certificate2 clientCert = GetClientCertificate("MySelfSignedCertificatePrivateKeyVersion");
                WebRequestHandler requestHandler = new WebRequestHandler();
                requestHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(clientCert);

                HttpClient client = new HttpClient(requestHandler)
                {
                    BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:7071/")
                };

                var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("login", "abc")
                };

                var postContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);

                HttpResponseMessage hrm = client.PostAsync("api/ClientCertificateTestFunctionName", postContent).Result;
                hrm.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                if (hrm.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                }

                HttpContent content = hrm.Content;
                string contentString = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                Console.WriteLine(hrm);
                Console.WriteLine(contentString);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = GenerateFullFlatMessage(ex, true);
                Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("END : {0}", System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);

            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static X509Certificate2 GetClientCertificate(string subjectName)
        {
            X509Store userCaStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            try
            {
                userCaStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
                X509Certificate2Collection certificatesInStore = userCaStore.Certificates;
                X509Certificate2Collection findResult = certificatesInStore.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, subjectName, true);
                X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = null;
                if (findResult.Count == 1)
                {
                    clientCertificate = findResult[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Unable to locate the correct client certificate.");
                }
                return clientCertificate;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                userCaStore.Close();
            }
        }

        private static string GenerateFullFlatMessage(Exception ex, bool showStackTrace)
        {
            string returnValue;

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            Exception nestedEx = ex;

            while (nestedEx != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nestedEx.Message))
                {
                    sb.Append(nestedEx.Message + System.Environment.NewLine);
                }

                if (showStackTrace && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(nestedEx.StackTrace))
                {
                    sb.Append(nestedEx.StackTrace + System.Environment.NewLine);
                }

                nestedEx = nestedEx.InnerException;
            }

            returnValue = sb.ToString();

            return returnValue;
        }
    }
}
```

The client code gets the certificate correctly.  The MySelfSignedCertificatePrivateKeyVersion is self signed, it has the private key.  The CA that signed this self-signed cert is in my Trust Root Authority.

The Azure Function does not see the client certificate.

My client response is:

*"NO CERT :(, login=abc"*

**Why is HttpRequestMessage.GetClientCertificate() failing?**

I know something is working, because I see the "abc" on the azure-function and the response.

Note, I am running my azure function in Visual Studio 2017 in debug mode.

**APPEND:**

Based on Tom-Sun answer, I was able to get it working when the function exists in azure.

Here is my slightly modified client code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GranadaCoder.SendWebRequests.ConsoleOne
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                ////ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

                /////////* Use the below to debug failed verification. */
                ////////ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
                ////////    new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback((
                ////////        sender,
                ////////        cert,
                ////////        chain,
                ////////        ssl) =>
                ////////{
                ////////    Console.WriteLine("ServerCertificateValidationCallback for Cert.Subject : '{0}'", cert.Subject);
                ////////    System.Net.HttpWebRequest hwr = sender as System.Net.HttpWebRequest;
                ////////    if (null != hwr)
                ////////    {
                ////////        SecurityShower.ShowHttpWebRequest(hwr);
                ////////    }

                ////////    //SecurityShower.ShowCertAndChain(cert, chain);
                ////////    return true;
                ////////});


                Console.WriteLine("START : {0}", System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);

                /* the kind of cert matters this one works, this kind of  certificate  worked
                 X509Extension.X509KeyUsageExtension.KeyUsages = 'CrlSign, KeyCertSign' */
                string thumbPrint = "0123456789012345678901234567890123456789";

                /* certicate that would not work */
                /*X509Extension.X509KeyUsageExtension.KeyUsages = 'KeyEncipherment, DigitalSignature' */
                //thumbPrint = "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890";

                X509Certificate2 clientCert = GetClientCertificate(thumbPrint);
                WebRequestHandler requestHandler = new WebRequestHandler();
                requestHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(clientCert);

                /* local not working */
                string baseUrl = "http://localhost:7071/";
                string suffixUrl = "api/ClientCertificateTestFunctionName";

                /* remote (azure published */
                baseUrl = "https://yourFunctionNameHere.azurewebsites.net/";
                suffixUrl = "api/ClientCertificateTestFunctionName";

                /* some vodoo to create the queryString, the "code" value is gotten via the azure-portal "Get function URL" while on the properties page of the azure function... NOTE, I had to get this value before I change clientCertEnabled to true (aka, when it was clientCertEnabled was false)  after I changed clientCertEnabled to true, the "extra" querystring of the azure function was not showing */
                var builder = new UriBuilder("http://www.wontactuallybeused.com");
                builder.Port = -1;
                var query = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(builder.Query);
                query["code"] = "NotForYouToSee0123456789012345678901234567890123456789==";
                builder.Query = query.ToString();
                string url = builder.ToString();
                suffixUrl += builder.Query;

                HttpClient client = new HttpClient(requestHandler)
                {
                    BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl)
                };

                var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("login", "abc")
                };

                var postContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);

                HttpResponseMessage hrm = client.PostAsync(suffixUrl, postContent).Result;
                //hrm.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                if (hrm.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                }

                HttpContent content = hrm.Content;
                string contentString = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                Console.WriteLine(hrm);
                Console.WriteLine(contentString);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = GenerateFullFlatMessage(ex, true);
                Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("END : {0}", System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);

            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static X509Certificate2 GetClientCertificate(string thumbprintValue)
        {
            thumbprintValue = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(thumbprintValue, @"[^\da-zA-z]", string.Empty).ToUpper();
            X509Store userCaStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            try
            {
                userCaStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
                X509Certificate2Collection certificatesInStore = userCaStore.Certificates;
                X509Certificate2Collection findResult = certificatesInStore.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprintValue, true);
                X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = null;
                if (findResult.Count == 1)
                {
                    clientCertificate = findResult[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Unable to locate the correct client certificate.");
                }
                return clientCertificate;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                userCaStore.Close();
            }
        }

        private static string GenerateFullFlatMessage(Exception ex, bool showStackTrace)
        {
            string returnValue;

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            Exception nestedEx = ex;

            while (nestedEx != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nestedEx.Message))
                {
                    sb.Append(nestedEx.Message + System.Environment.NewLine);
                }

                if (showStackTrace && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(nestedEx.StackTrace))
                {
                    sb.Append(nestedEx.StackTrace + System.Environment.NewLine);
                }

                nestedEx = nestedEx.InnerException;
            }

            returnValue = sb.ToString();

            return returnValue;
        }
    }
}
```

and an optional helper

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public static class SecurityShower
    {
        public static void ShowHttpWebRequest(System.Net.HttpWebRequest hwr)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if (null != hwr)
            {
                sb.Append("-----------------------------------------------HttpWebRequest" + System.Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append(string.Format("HttpWebRequest.Address.AbsolutePath='{0}'", hwr.Address.AbsolutePath) + System.Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append(string.Format("HttpWebRequest.Address.AbsoluteUri='{0}'", hwr.Address.AbsoluteUri) + System.Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append(string.Format("HttpWebRequest.Address='{0}'", hwr.Address) + System.Environment.NewLine);

                sb.Append(string.Format("HttpWebRequest.RequestUri.AbsolutePath='{0}'", hwr.RequestUri.AbsolutePath) + System.Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append(string.Format("HttpWebRequest.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri='{0}'", hwr.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri) + System.Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append(string.Format("HttpWebRequest.RequestUri='{0}'", hwr.RequestUri) + System.Environment.NewLine);

                foreach (X509Certificate cert in hwr.ClientCertificates)
                {
                    sb.Append("START*************************************************");
                    ShowX509Certificate(sb, cert);
                    sb.Append("END*************************************************");
                }
            }

            string result = sb.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        public static void ShowCertAndChain(X509Certificate2 cert)
        {
            X509Chain chain = new X509Chain();
            chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.EntireChain;
            chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Offline;
            chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.AllFlags;

            ////chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.IgnoreCtlSignerRevocationUnknown &&
            ////X509VerificationFlags.IgnoreRootRevocationUnknown &&
            ////X509VerificationFlags.IgnoreEndRevocationUnknown &&
            ////X509VerificationFlags.IgnoreCertificateAuthorityRevocationUnknown &&
            ////X509VerificationFlags.IgnoreCtlNotTimeValid;

            chain.Build(cert);

            ShowCertAndChain(cert, chain);
        }

        public static void ShowCertAndChain(X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if (null != cert)
            {
                ShowX509Certificate(sb, cert);
            }

            if (null != chain)
            {
                sb.Append("-X509Chain(Start)-" + System.Environment.NewLine);
                ////sb.Append(string.Format("Cert.ChainStatus='{0}'", string.Join(",", chain.ChainStatus.ToList())) + System.Environment.NewLine);

                foreach (X509ChainStatus cstat in chain.ChainStatus)
                {
                    sb.Append(string.Format("X509ChainStatus::'{0}'-'{1}'", cstat.Status.ToString(), cstat.StatusInformation) + System.Environment.NewLine);
                }

                X509ChainElementCollection ces = chain.ChainElements;
                ShowX509ChainElementCollection(sb, ces);
                sb.Append("-X509Chain(End)-" + System.Environment.NewLine);
            }

            string result = sb.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        private static void ShowX509Extension(StringBuilder sb, int x509ExtensionCount, X509Extension ext)
        {
            sb.Append(string.Empty + System.Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append(string.Format("--------X509ExtensionNumber(Start):{0}", x509ExtensionCount) + System.Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append(string.Format("X509Extension.Critical='{0}'", ext.Critical) + System.Environment.NewLine);

            AsnEncodedData asndata = new AsnEncodedData(ext.Oid, ext.RawData);
            sb.Append(string.Format("Extension type: {0}", ext.Oid.FriendlyName) + System.Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append(string.Format("Oid value: {0}", asndata.Oid.Value) + System.Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append(string.Format("Raw data length: {0} {1}", asndata.RawData.Length, Environment.NewLine) + System.Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append(asndata.Format(true) + System.Environment.NewLine);

            X509BasicConstraintsExtension basicEx = ext as X509BasicConstraintsExtension;
            if (null != basicEx)
            {
                sb.Append("-X509BasicConstraintsExtension-" + System.Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append(string.Format("X509Extension.X509BasicConstraintsExtension.CertificateAuthority='{0}'", basicEx.CertificateAuthority) + System.Environment.NewLine);
            }

            X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension keyEx = ext as X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension;
            if (null != keyEx)
            {
                sb.Append("-X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension-" + System.Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append(string.Format("X509Extension.X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension.EnhancedKeyUsages='{0}'", keyEx.EnhancedKeyUsages) + System.Environment.NewLine);
                foreach (Oid oi in keyEx.EnhancedKeyUsages)
                {
                    sb.Append(string.Format("------------EnhancedKeyUsages.Oid.FriendlyName='{0}'", oi.FriendlyName) + System.Environment.NewLine);
                    sb.Append(string.Format("------------EnhancedKeyUsages.Oid.Value='{0}'", oi.Value) + System.Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }

            X509KeyUsageExtension usageEx = ext as X509KeyUsageExtension;
            if (null != usageEx)
            {
                sb.Append("-X509KeyUsageExtension-" + System.Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append(string.Format("X509Extension.X509KeyUsageExtension.KeyUsages='{0}'", usageEx.KeyUsages) + System.Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append(string.Format("X509KeyUsageExtension.KeyUsages.X509KeyUsageFlags.CrlSign='{0}'", (usageEx.KeyUsages & X509KeyUsageFlags.CrlSign) != 0) + System.Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append(string.Format("X509KeyUsageExtension.KeyUsages.X509KeyUsageFlags.DataEncipherment='{0}'", (usageEx.KeyUsages & X509KeyUsageFlags.DataEncipherment) != 0) + System.Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append(string.Format("X509KeyUsageExtension.KeyUsages.X509KeyUsageFlags.DecipherOnly='{0}'", (usageEx.KeyUsages & X509KeyUsageFlags.DecipherOnly) != 0) + System.Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append(string.Format("X509KeyUsageExtension.KeyUsages.X509KeyUsageFlags.DigitalSignature='{0}'", (usageEx.KeyUsages & X509KeyUsageFlags.DigitalSignature) != 0) + System.Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append(string.Format("X509KeyUsageExtension.KeyUsages.X509KeyUsageFlags.EncipherOnly='{0}'", (usageEx.KeyUsages & X509KeyUsageFlags.EncipherOnly) != 0) + System.Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append(string.Format("X509KeyUsageExtension.KeyUsages.X509KeyUsageFlags.KeyAgreement='{0}'", (usageEx.KeyUsages & X509KeyUsageFlags.KeyAgreement) != 0) + System.Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append(string.Format("X509KeyUsageExtension.KeyUsages.X509KeyUsageFlags.KeyCertSign='{0}'", (usageEx.KeyUsages & X509KeyUsageFlags.KeyCertSign) != 0) + System.Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append(string.Format("X509KeyUsageExtension.KeyUsages.X509KeyUsageFlags.KeyEncipherment='{0}'", (usageEx.KeyUsages & X509KeyUsageFlags.KeyEncipherment) != 0) + System.Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append(string.Format("X509KeyUsageExtension.KeyUsages.X509KeyUsageFlags.None='{0}'", (usageEx.KeyUsages & X509KeyUsageFlags.None) != 0) + System.Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append(string.Format("X509KeyUsageExtension.KeyUsages.X509KeyUsageFlags.NonRepudiation='{0}'", (usageEx.KeyUsages & X509KeyUsageFlags.NonRepudiation) != 0) + System.Environment.NewLine);
            }

            X509SubjectKeyIdentifierExtension skIdEx = ext as X509SubjectKeyIdentifierExtension;
            if (null != skIdEx)
            {
                sb.Append("-X509SubjectKeyIdentifierExtension-" + System.Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append(string.Format("X509Extension.X509SubjectKeyIdentifierExtension.Oid='{0}'", skIdEx.Oid) + System.Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append(string.Format("X509Extension.X509SubjectKeyIdentifierExtension.SubjectKeyIdentifier='{0}'", skIdEx.SubjectKeyIdentifier) + System.Environment.NewLine);
            }

            sb.Append(string.Format("--------X509ExtensionNumber(End):{0}", x509ExtensionCount) + System.Environment.NewLine);
        }

        private static void ShowX509Extensions(StringBuilder sb, string cert2SubjectName, X509ExtensionCollection extColl)
        {
            int x509ExtensionCount = 0;
            sb.Append(string.Format("--------ShowX509Extensions(Start):for:{0}", cert2SubjectName) + System.Environment.NewLine);
            foreach (X509Extension ext in extColl)
            {
                ShowX509Extension(sb, ++x509ExtensionCount, ext);
            }

            sb.Append(string.Format("--------ShowX509Extensions(End):for:{0}", cert2SubjectName) + System.Environment.NewLine);
        }

        private static void ShowX509Certificate2(StringBuilder sb, X509Certificate2 cert2)
        {
            if (null != cert2)
            {
                sb.Append(string.Format("X509Certificate2.SubjectName.Name='{0}'", cert2.SubjectName.Name) + System.Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append(string.Format("X509Certificate2.Subject='{0}'", cert2.Subject) + System.Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append(string.Format("X509Certificate2.Thumbprint='{0}'", cert2.Thumbprint) + System.Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append(string.Format("X509Certificate2.HasPrivateKey='{0}'", cert2.HasPrivateKey) + System.Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append(string.Format("X509Certificate2.Version='{0}'", cert2.Version) + System.Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append(string.Format("X509Certificate2.NotBefore='{0}'", cert2.NotBefore) + System.Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append(string.Format("X509Certificate2.NotAfter='{0}'", cert2.NotAfter) + System.Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append(string.Format("X509Certificate2.PublicKey.Key.KeySize='{0}'", cert2.PublicKey.Key.KeySize) + System.Environment.NewLine);

                ////List<X509KeyUsageExtension> keyUsageExtensions = cert2.Extensions.OfType<X509KeyUsageExtension>().ToList();
                ////List<X509Extension> extensions = cert2.Extensions.OfType<X509Extension>().ToList();

                ShowX509Extensions(sb, cert2.Subject, cert2.Extensions);
            }
        }

        private static void ShowX509ChainElementCollection(StringBuilder sb, X509ChainElementCollection ces)
        {
            int x509ChainElementCount = 0;
            foreach (X509ChainElement ce in ces)
            {
                sb.Append(string.Empty + System.Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append(string.Format("----X509ChainElementNumber:{0}", ++x509ChainElementCount) + System.Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append(string.Format("X509ChainElement.Cert.SubjectName.Name='{0}'", ce.Certificate.SubjectName.Name) + System.Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append(string.Format("X509ChainElement.Cert.Issuer='{0}'", ce.Certificate.Issuer) + System.Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append(string.Format("X509ChainElement.Cert.Thumbprint='{0}'", ce.Certificate.Thumbprint) + System.Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append(string.Format("X509ChainElement.Cert.HasPrivateKey='{0}'", ce.Certificate.HasPrivateKey) + System.Environment.NewLine);

                X509Certificate2 cert2 = ce.Certificate as X509Certificate2;
                ShowX509Certificate2(sb, cert2);

                ShowX509Extensions(sb, cert2.Subject, ce.Certificate.Extensions);
            }
        }

        private static void ShowX509Certificate(StringBuilder sb, X509Certificate cert)
        {
            sb.Append("-----------------------------------------------" + System.Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append(string.Format("Cert.Subject='{0}'", cert.Subject) + System.Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append(string.Format("Cert.Issuer='{0}'", cert.Issuer) + System.Environment.NewLine);

            sb.Append(string.Format("Cert.GetPublicKey().Length='{0}'", cert.GetPublicKey().Length) + System.Environment.NewLine);

            X509Certificate2 cert2 = cert as X509Certificate2;
            ShowX509Certificate2(sb, cert2);
        }
    }
}
```

Good read(s)

http://www.razibinrais.com/secure-web-api-with-client-certificate/

Comment: For Azure WebApps, the client cert is flowed to application via a request header "X-ARR-ClientCert" instead.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth

Comment: @Suwat.  I changed my code above, and now I check for GetClientCertificate and i check for that header (X-ARR-ClientCert) and both are there.  I kinda wonder if GetClientCertificate is just a wrapper for looking at that header (??) Not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is HttpRequestMessage.GetClientCertificate() failing?

I test your code on my side. I found that if I locally debug it then I can reproduce that you mentioned, on the Azure platform if I change the **clientCertEnabled** to `true` then it works as expected. More details please refer to to [Configure Web App for Client Certificate Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth#configure-web-app-for-client-certificate-authentication). If anyone who how to enable clientCertEnabled locally please add the comment.

> To setup your web app to require client certificates you need to add the clientCertEnabled site setting for your web app and set it to true. This setting is not currently available through the management experience in the Portal, and the REST API will need to be used to accomplish this.
>   You can use the ARMClient tool to make it easy to craft the REST API call. After you log in with the tool you will need to issue the following

```
ARMClient PUT subscriptions/{Subscription Id}/resourcegroups/{Resource Group Name}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{Website Name}?api-version=2015-04-01 @enableclientcert.json -verbose
```

I change clientCertEnabled with [azure resources](https://resources.azure.com)

[image]

Test with client code:

[image]

**Note:** Currently, if we set the clientCertEnabled as true, then all of requests to azure function will require certification

Comment: Tom.  What "path" did you take in the Azure-Resources-Explorer to get to this setting?  (can't see via the partial screen shot).  I'm fishing around there now and can't find it.

Comment: Azure Resouce link: https://resources.azure.com/, I also mentioned in my answer. Search the azure function name  then we could get it, details could refer to the screenshot. **Note**: we need to change 'read'-> 'read/write' then we edit the value and put the request with Azure Resource.

Comment: Resource link: `https://resources.azure.com/subscriptions/{Subscription Id}/resourcegroups/{Resource Group Name}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{FunctionAppName}`

Comment: I had everything up to "providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{AzureFunctionAppName}".. that is what I needed.  Thanks.

Comment: I got it working when it is published to azure.  Local debugging remains a mystery.  I'll leave this question un-answered in hope of a clue for debugging.  I appended my answer with a few additional notes.

Comment: Based on my understanding, it seems that azure function prevent client certificate by default. But I don't figure it out how to set `clientCertEnabled`  to true in local. My workaround is that we could use custom header in the Azure/local for test. Add the certificate info into the customized header then we could get the certificate info from the customized header and convert to certificate for authentication. We also could give [our idea](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps) to azure team.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking last night I need to post this at the suggestions site.  I played with the "X-ARR-ClientCert" header yesterday...but I got the same results (its there on azure, not there locally).  I may have to implement the custom-header idea.  SInce I don't think there is an answer to "local" issue, I'll mark as answer.  Thx for your efforts here.

Comment: I posted the idea on the "idea" site....FYI.  I don't think they've reviewed it yet.